# CSV Date Format not Saving for SQL Import

Tags: csv, date

I am having trouble importing a csv to gradresql. The date is DD-MM-YYYY and I need to change it in csv to text YYYY MM DD - have tried everything I could find on the web.

I tried:
to format cells
created a new column =text(cell,"YYYY-MM-DD") copied and pasted as values
changed and tried to save as an excel doc and then save as csv
saved as txt doc

Comment: can you show the first two lines of the CSV when you open it with Notepad?